# Angles of lines tangential to a circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles, spherical-trigonometry

I am looking to find the angles of line features relative to the tangent of a circle. Please see [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjL6i.jpg) for general idea.  Angles to line features (purple) I am looking for are (poorly drawn) black hashes, which are relative to the yellow hashed tangents.

I would ultimately like the outcome to be in polar coordinates (0=East, 270=South) and referenced from 0 to 180.  The only data I am provided are coordinates to the start/end of my lines (see example link).  I have standardized all of my (**purple**) **lines** to have a starting $x_0$ coordinate to be the south-most location, giving $\Delta x \geqslant 0$.  So my $y$ values will swing in direction, causing $\Delta y$ values to be both positive and negative.  This is not the case for the spokes (orange).

I am not a mathematician. To figure this out I have been drawing schematics for each quadrant to determine the relative $\theta$ equations.  I was successful for a few test examples in Excel but when applied to all my lines, I found outcomes that were not right.  My nested if/and statement is quite long.  If anyone would like me to post, I will adjust for clarity.

I have also tried a dot product equation :

$$\arccos\left(\frac{(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)\centerdot(y_1-x_1)}{\left[\text{length between}\: (x_0,y_0) \:\text{and} \: (x_1,y_1)\right]\times\left[(\text{length between}\: (x_1,y_1) \:\text{and} \: (x_2,y_2)\right]}\right)  $$
I am getting angles between 1 and 2.5.

Is there a tested method or equation that I am unaware of to determine angles relative to the tangent of a circle?

This is an image of my actual lines with spokes radiating from my $(x_0, y_0)$ centerpoint to each bend in my fractures (lines).  I have quite a few, hence automation is key...

[Actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75ztt.jpg)

Much appreciated!

Comment: You say angle of lines tangent to a circle. If a line is tangent to a circle what angle would it have?   After reviewing your picture it looks like you're trying to determine the angle an arbitrary line in R^2 would make if you were to place it tangent to the circle.

Comment: If you want to know the angle the tangential point makes with respect to the circle just check that by shifting the line to the origin. Maybe I misunderstood what you're searching for.

Comment: Thank you in and out o' mind.  You are right, I will make some changes to my question to clarify.

Comment: You have an arbitrary line, you want the angle between this line and the line that is tangent to the circle from the right side, we'll say 0 till it could have possibly rotated to 180.

Comment: I'm sure you probably know from geometry that the alternate interior angles are equal.

Comment: Correct in and out o' mind.  Am I approaching this problem in the wrong way?  Making it more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: I think if you translate the line you've labelled with three points down to the origin and the tangent line you can subtract the larger angle, which would be the tangent line in this case, from the smaller angle. Then by the alternate interior angle theorem you've got your angle in that one case. There may be an easier way but it could be harder depending on perspective, linear algebra, I can't think of that solution.

Comment: The translation of the lines is only helpful in determining where they intersect the circle so that you could get the angle.

Comment: You may be able to use parametric lines and stuff along the lines of what you've tried, dot product, etc. , I haven't done that in a while so I would have to think about it.

Comment: A simplification could be that a tangent line is perpendicular to the radius so it's angle in radians is pi/2. Say the tangent 'touchs' the circle at 30 degrees, which is pi/6. The angle it would therefore make with respect the original axes would be their sum, pi/2+pi/6 which you could them use to find the angle of your line in the method I described.

Comment: R/D=2pi/360=pi/180,     R:=radians and D:= degrees. This will be helpful in converting. I'm honestly unsure of your background, you may know this or that and this too trivial, etc. I hope I helped.

Comment: I suspect that you really mean $(y_1-y_0, x_0-x_1)$ instead of $(y_1-x_1)$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem that you’re running into is in the way that your endpoint data are stored: it’s making this somewhat more complicated than it needs to be. If we turn all of those lines in your diagram into vectors, it appears that you’re looking for the angle between a vector that is rotated 90° clockwise from a radial line and a vector that points “away” from the circle. Once you have these two vectors, computing the angle between them is a straightforward calculation that can be done using the dot product, as you’ve mentioned. Unfortunately, because the endpoints are stored with the least $x$-coordinate first, you can’t simply subtract the first point from the second to get the vector that you need for this calculation.

What it comes down to is determining the correct orientation for the vector that represents the target line. Looking closely at the diagram again, we want it oriented so that it’s at an angle $0\lt\theta\lt\pi$ counterclockwise from the “tangent” vector. This is precisely the condition for their cross product to point in the positive $z$ direction (if we view them as 3-D vectors, that is), which suggests the following procedure:

Set $\mathbf v=\langle y_1-y_0,x_0-x_1\rangle$, $\Delta x=x_3-x_2$ and $\Delta y=y_3-y_2$. If you like, you can normalize $\mathbf v$ now by dividing it by its length. Compute $\mathbf{v}_x\Delta x+\mathbf{v}_y\Delta y$ (this is the $z$-component of the cross product) and examine its sign. If it’s zero, the angle is zero and you’re done. If it’s positive, you’ve got the correct orientation, so set $\mathbf w=\langle\Delta x,\Delta y\rangle$; if negative, you need to flip this vector, so set $\mathbf w=-\langle\Delta x,\Delta y\rangle$. A compact way to express this is $$\mathbf w=\operatorname{signum}(\mathbf{v}_x\Delta x+\mathbf{v}_y\Delta y)\,\langle\Delta x,\Delta y\rangle$$ (you can use the `SIGN` function for this in Excel). Now you can compute the angle between them using $$\cos\theta={\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w\over\|\mathbf v\|\|\mathbf w\|}$$ and be assured of getting the right one.

Since $\|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b\|=\|\mathbf a\|\|\mathbf b\|\sin\theta$, you could also recover the angle from the cross product, but then you’d have to do more checking to figure out which of the possible angles is the correct one.